# Error Message C++

Tags: c++, b-tree

I got this error message when trying to compile my code:

`btree.h:23: error: expected unqualified-id before 'template'`

it comes from this line:

`template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const btree<T>& tree);`

there is absolutely nothing above this line except a bunch of comments and a couple of `#include` library files, which are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

#include "btree_iterator.h"
```

my btree_iterator.h holds:

```
template <typename T>
class btree_iterator  {


}
```

if someone could tell me whats wrong it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Re: "there is absolutely nothing above this line..." - Clearly the compiler disagrees with you. Unfortunately without knowing exactly what's in `btree_iterator.h` I can't make out what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: "btree_iterator.h" almost certainly contains the issue

Comment: @Ayjay @In silico check OP to see whats in `btree_iterator.h`, there isn't anything worth noting in the class

Comment: Your class declaration is missing the ending `;`. Make sure the class before it also has the `;`.

Comment: The evil typo made it again ... You missed a semicolon at the end of the class declaration.

Comment: i'm getting this error as well after i fix that damn `;` `btree.h:25: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token`

Comment: Why is a semicolon required there anyway? It seems like its only purpose in life is to slow down development by allowing coders to forget it. It would be completely backwards compatible to drop it anyway - you can have empty statements wherever you want.

Comment: @Ayjay: That's what other languages that appeared after C++ did.

Comment: nevermind i forgot to add `template <class T> btree; in my `btree_iterator.h`file

Comment: @Ayjay: The reason the semicolon is required after a class declaration is because you're allowed to declare instances of that class between the closing brace and the semicolon, e.g. `class A { ... } anA;` declares an instance of class `A` named `anA`.  Whether or not this is a *useful* feature can be debated, but I'm betting it was put in the language in order to be backwards compatible with C in this regard (with `struct` in place of `class`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon:

```
template <typename T>
class btree_iterator  {


};
 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment that line out and put a very simple line, maybe a `typedef char mychar;` If you get an error on that line then you can figure out that the actual mistake is at the end of `btree_iterator.h`.

Because in C and C++ include files just paste the contents of the include file. If there is a typo in the include file, perhaps a missing semicolon, that carries through into the original file.

Comment: i just tried that, and it complains that `btree.h:23: error: template declaration of 'typedef'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring it within the class, you should templatize the class itself and directly define this within it.

```
template<typename T>
class btree {

   //your overloaded function here without the beginning template declaration
};
```

Also with template classes, you cannot separate the class into a strictly header(.h) and implementation(.cpp) file because then the compiler will not be able to create the correct objects at runtime as if it can only see the header. So in the same '.h' file, write both the declaration and definition.